# Dialogflow, chatbot for workplace

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I wanted to know if it's possible to make a chatbot for workplace with Dialogflow and if it is how?. Because I made one just to test it, on a facebook site a created. I want to make the same one for my workplace. I would appreciate some help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and what you have attempted so far. Update your question.

Answer (score 1):

the Workchat of Workplace works exactly as Messenger so quick answer is yes. Once you have created your chatbot you can go in the Integrations page in Dialogflow and activate the integration with Messenger. You will have to put there the access code that you can create from the Integration dashboard from Workplace (admin panel --> integrations --> create custom integration).

The Workplace integration must have, at least, permissions for:
- Message any member

and the webhook configured for Page --> Messages

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do?

Suppose you are making a chatbot for HR.

Yes, you can do that by starting with FAQs (Frequently asked questions). This is the best thing to start as it's not very complex.

Yes, you can link it to Facebook where people in your workplace can access this chatbot on Facebook chat.

Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes it´s possible!

You need to create the bot inside the Workplace, and link inside Dialogflow same as you did with Facebook.

If you need some help, ask me!